# Get Discord username and discriminator through a mention

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have tried reading the docs, but I don't understand what is going on here and how to fix it. I am trying to map a mention to its proper `Name#NNNN` form, but alas, it is proving to be a fruitless endeavor for me.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from collections import defaultdict

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
     print('Ready!')


jobz = {}
'''PART 1 v v v'''

@client.event
if message.content.startswith('>jobsched'):
        author = message.author
        jobz[author].append(...)
        await channel.send(jobz[author])


'''PART 2 v v v'''

if message.content.startswith('>when '):
        channel = message.channel
        worker = list(filter(None, message.content[6:].split(' ')))[0]
        uname = message.mentions[0].mention
        await channel.send(jobz[uname])
```

PART 1:
I run this first, the send works as expected as seen below:

```
>jobsched 'a'
>jobsched 'b'
```

As seen in the last line, this spits out `['1a', '2b']`

PART 2:
Here is where I have my issue.

```
>when @Name
```

I **expected** this to spit out `['1a', '2b']` because I expected it to look up or translate the mentioned name, find its respective name and discriminator. I thought this should happen since, in the above piece, that is how the name gets written into the dictionary is i.e. Name#1234: `['1a','2b']`

Printing out `.keys()` shows that the key has the name and discriminator i.e. `Name#1234` in the 'jobz' dictionary.

However, I can't seem to get the mention to give me the Name and Discriminator. I have tried doing `mentions[0].mention` from what I have seen here on stackoverflow, but it doesn't result in a `Member class` for me, just a string, presumably just '@Name'. If I leave it alone, as shown in my 'worker' variable, it passes an empty list. It should pull the list because when I override it to `jobz['Name#1234']` it gives me the list I expect.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You should try `print(message.mentions[0].mention)`. The result might surprise you :) I expounded on why in a comment on @effprime's answer.

Comment: You shouldn't be using on_message for commands.

Comment: @FluxedScript Sorry, this is all new to me and I did it on a whim. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for
I was just doing it like the example I saw here.  How should I properly rewrite this?

Comment: That would be another questions @andru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mentions` is a list of Member objects, so when you do `mentions[0]` you are referencing a Member. Thus, `mentions[0].mention` is the formatted mention string for the first-mentioned (element 0) Member.

You probably want `mentions[0].name` and `mentions[0].discriminator`

See: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions

Comment: This is correct. `Member.mention` will return a string suitable for mentioning that member, but it will NOT look like `MyName#1234`; instead, it will be the internal representation that looks something like: `<@80351110224678912>`. [Relevant documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting-formats).

Answer (score 2):

just cast the member object to string to get the name and discriminator [as it says in the discord.py docs.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) To mention someone, put the internal representation like this: `f'<@{member.id}>'`. To stop problems like this, use `client.command()` it's way easier to put in parameters, and easier to access info. So, here would be the code:

```py
@client.command()
async def when(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(jobz[str(member)])
```

Also, if your worker variable is returning `None`, you're not passing a parameter at all

Comment: `Member.mention` returns the same string as `f'<@{member.id}>'`.